# Acceder a TRM actual desde PHP

Tags: php

Consulta se podrá acceder a la API Google de cambio de divisas para consultar el TRM actual (USD y COP). He encontrados varios scripts de PHP y los he probado pero sin resultados. la idea es consultar el TRM actual y mostrarlo al usuario:

```
<?php
    function currencyConverter($from_currency, $to_currency, $amount) {
        $amount = urlencode($amount);
        $from = urlencode($from_currency);
        $to = urlencode($to_currency);
        $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from=?$to";
        $ch = @curl_init();
        $timeout= 0;
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
        $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
        $var = $data['0'];
        return round($var,3);
    }
    //amount
    $amount =1;
    //From Currency
    $from_currency ="USD";
    //To Currenc
    $to_currency ="COP";
    $converted_currency = currencyConverter($from_currency, $to_currency, $amount);
    echo $converted_currency
?>
```

Pero no funciona, segui buscando y encontré este otro:

```
 <?php
    function conversor_monedas($moneda_origen,$moneda_destino,$cantidad) {
        $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$cantidad&from=$moneda_origen&to=$moneda_destino");
        $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
        $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);  
        return preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
    }
    echo conversor_monedas("USD","COP",1);
?>
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar, probé este otro codigo pero tampoco:

```
 <?php
    function conversor_monedas($moneda_origen,$moneda_destino,$cantidad) {
        $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$cantidad&from=$moneda_origen&to=$moneda_destino");
        $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
        $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);  
        return preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
    }
    // change amount according to your needs
    $amount =1;
    // change From Currency according to your needs
    $from_Curr ='COP';
    // change To Currency according to your needs
    $to_Curr ='USD';
    $converted_currency=currencyConverter($from_Curr, $to_Curr, $amount);
    // Print outout
    echo $converted_currency;
?>
```

Agradezco, si me echan una ayuda al respecto..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colegas, después de tanto buscar; encontré un script que me sirvió. Lo comparto por si a alguien más le pueda servir.

```
<?php
    $date = date("Y-m-d");//Fecha actual
    try {
        $soap = new soapclient("https://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SuperfinancieraWebServiceTRM/TCRMServicesWebService/TCRMServicesWebService?WSDL", array(
            'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
            'trace' => 1,
            "location" => "http://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SuperfinancieraWebServiceTRM/TCRMServicesWebService/TCRMServicesWebService",
        ));
        $response = $soap->queryTCRM(array('tcrmQueryAssociatedDate' => $date));
        $response = $response->return;
        if($response->success){
            echo $response->value;
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Gracias por la sugerencia, la información la saqué del siguiente link:
https://gist.github.com/cdiaz/b4da1cb546ab13a0e9e63212baf2aa80

Lo que hice en mi caso fue mostrar el TRM dentro de un label:

```
<label class="label" id="trm"><strong>
    <?php
        $date = date("Y-m-d");//Fecha actual
        try {
            $soap = new soapclient("https://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SuperfinancieraWebServiceTRM/TCRMServicesWebService/TCRMServicesWebService?WSDL", array(
                'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
                'trace' => 1,
                "location" => "http://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SuperfinancieraWebServiceTRM/TCRMServicesWebService/TCRMServicesWebService",
            ));
            $response = $soap->queryTCRM(array('tcrmQueryAssociatedDate' => $date));
            $response = $response->return;
            if($response->success){
                echo $response->value;
            }
        } catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
</strong></label>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).